# ASP.Net and Entity Framework Filter Search to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, entity-framework-4

I am working on ASP.NET application which is using Entity Framework and getting data from a Database. I have following code to filter rendering data on a Grid View. I tried this code which it wrong for sure!

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GISEntities gis = new GISEntities();
            GIS_CONTRACTOR_TEST tbl = gis.GIS_CONTRACTOR_TEST.ToList().Where(x => x.CONTRACTORNAME == txtSearch.Text).First();
            GridView1.DataSource = tbl.CONTRACTORNAME;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

As you can see I have problem on  `GridView1.DataSource = tbl.CONTRACTORNAME;` which I couldn't find any other property for `tbl` except of field constructors. Can you please let me know how I can filter the database into a grid View instead of displaying them separately!

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error or are you getting results other than expected?

Comment: well this code is logically wrong! I want to get the result in gridview but I am accessing only to the columns property from tbl.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
GISEntities gis = new GISEntities();
GridView1.DataSource = gis.GIS_CONTRACTOR_TEST.Where(m => m.CONTRACTORNAME == txtSearch.Text).ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks G RAvinder, just can you please also let me know how I can check if there is any thing to return or not? I mean sending a message to the users if there wasn't any matches in the database?

Comment: just use
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1">
 <EmptyDataTemplate>No results found.</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
it will show "No results found." when there no matching results in database.

Answer (score 2):

If I was to assume `GISEntities` is your database context then try this.

```
var result = (from a in gis.GIS_CONTRACTOR_TEST where a.CONTRACTORNAME == txtSearch.Text select a).ToList();

GridView1.DataSource = result;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

If you're not finding the correct properties in the `result` variable I would take a look at your `GIS_CONTRACTOR_TEST` model and database context, making sure it is defined correctly.

Comment: Merci Reza, but I am getting "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource." error on running your code!

Comment: Thanks Reza, it is working now. just one quick question? Are yo using the Linq to query the data? so what is different between your method by using "from a in gis.CONTRACTOR.TEST where.... select a" and Where() which G Ravinder used?

Comment: I am using linq query, the final result shouldn't be different than what you were doing. It's what I prefer personally over calling Where() and what not.